# proof question: (Prove that $V=R(T^k) \oplus N(T^k)$ for some positive integer k)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be linear.

a).if $\mathrm{rank} (T)= \mathrm{rank} (T^2)$, prove $R(T) \bigcap N(T)$={0}.

b). Prove that $V=R(T^k) \oplus N(T^k)$ for some positive integer k.

For b), am I supposed to use dimension theorem and by construction, argue that no matter the integer k, dimension of $R(T^k)$ are always equal? Will the proof be straightaway then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Note that $\ker(T) \subset \ker(T^2)$ because $T(x) = 0$ implies $T(T(x)) = 0$. The equality you're positing is that $\dim \ker(T) = \dim \ker(T^2)$, by the rank-nullity theorem. It follows that $\ker(T) = \ker(T^2)$.

So now assume that $x \in \ker(T) \cap \operatorname{im}(T)$. Then $x = T(x')$ for some $x'$, because $x \in \operatorname{im}(T)$. But then $T(x) = T(T(x')) = 0$. It follows from $\ker(T) = \ker(T^2)$ that $T(x') = 0$, which is to say, $x = 0$.

For (b), see the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296209/prove-that-there-is-a-positive-integer-m-such-that-v-kertm-oplus-operator?rq=1).

Comment: I couldn't find related for b). Thanks!